# Making a web request and getting request in JSON format in android

Tags: android

I am trying to accomplish the task of

Making a Web request
                              ->getting result in JSON format
                                                                    ->Parsing the result
                                                                                               -> and finally display the result in a table....

Any help regarding any of the task is welcome....

Comment: Post the code you already have written.

Comment: HttpClient or URLConnection -> Huh? Service should return this -> Gson or JSONObject -> Use Adapter

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll leave you to display the results, but the first bit can be accomplished as follows:

```
URLConnection connection = new URL("http://example.com/someService.jsp").openConnection();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()), 1024 * 16);
StringBuffer builder = new StringBuffer();
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
  builder.append(line).append("\n");
}
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
```

Comment: +1 for a good answer. Would have been perfect if there was an example of how one can enumerate the JSON object.